# ^M charcter in vi editor

Tags: python, csv, append

I am new to python. I am trying to append the CSV file.

Code is working. But when I do vi `test2.csv` I see a `^M` charcter at the end of line.

When I do `cat` or `less` in Unix box I don't see the character. Even CSV looks ok.

Can you please advise what might be the issue.

```
with open('test.csv','r') as csvfile:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   next(csv_reader)
   with open('test2.csv','a') as newfile:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(newfile)
      for line in csv_reader:
          csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Check this for more details about the case https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32003

Comment: The question has a detailed answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: Can we do something in python script itself for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files have (CR/LF) as end of file, by standard:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

> MS-DOS-style lines that end with (CR/LF) characters (optional for the
>   last line).

Yet, you may omit CR and most of the readers can read such files fine.

`vi` is a pure test editor in Linux, and for text files, it expects only LF and shows those CRs.

Hamza Abdaoui provided nice reference about it https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/32003#32003

Any dedicated CSV-reader cares for (CR/LF) properly. 
For instance, the python csv module does this. 
So, when you read with `csv.reader` you drop CRs. 
But, when you save as it with `csv.writer` it forces (CR/LF) into output file.

You may alter such behavior using `lineterminator`

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(newfile, lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much.